# Symfony2: No route found for "GET /lucky/controller/"

Tags: symfony, controller, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to get started with Symfony2 and I'm getting stuck on the "create your first page" tutorial : http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/page_creation.html

I created the controller file (copy-pasted from tutorial) as **E:\Web\project\src\AppBundle\Controller\LuckyController.php** :

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Controller/LuckyController.php
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class LuckyController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/lucky/number")
     */
    public function numberAction()
    {
        $number = rand(0, 100);

        return new Response(
            '<html><body>Lucky number: '.$number.'</body></html>'
        );
    }
}
```

I didn't make any change to any other file.

When I go to the URL **127.0.0.1/project/web/app_dev.php/lucky/controller** (127.0.0.1 is the virtual host for E:\Web) I keep getting the error "*No route found for "GET /lucky/controller"*".

> 404 Not Found - NotFoundHttpException
>   1 linked Exception:
>   [2/2] NotFoundHttpException: No route found for "GET /lucky/controller/"
>   [1/2] ResourceNotFoundException:

If I remove the "/web" from the URL, **127.0.0.1/project/app_dev.php/lucky/controller**, I get a 404 error.

I'm pretty sure the error comes from the folder structure since the files are unmodified. Similar issue was reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31919257/symfony2-no-route-found-for-get-lucky-number) but none of these suggestions solved my error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful, your route is `/lucky/number` not `/lucky/controller`.

So, you have to try with `127.0.0.1/project/web/app_dev.php/lucky/number`

Answer (score 1):

Just figured out that the URL should be **127.0.0.1/project/web/app_dev.php/lucky/number** (and not **controller**). Problem solved.